# how to create new module in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Is there any simple way to create new module in Laravel, if yes then please explain in detail.

Need to create new custom module in Laravel for users, product etc but didnt understand how to proceed with the same.

Answer (score 4):

You should be right to go with

```php
php artisan module:make <module_name>
```

You can also create multiple modules at once doing this:

```php
php artisan module:make Users Products
```

this command will create all the resources you need like `controller`, `seed` class service provider and scaffold all the routes. If you dont want all this create new module with the following command

```php
php artisan module:make Products --plain
```

Answer (score 2):

To install through Composer, by run the following command:

```
composer require nwidart/laravel-modules
```

The package will automatically register a service provider and alias.

Optionally, publish the package's configuration file by running:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Nwidart\Modules\LaravelModulesServiceProvider"
```

By default the module classes are not loaded automatically. You can autoload your modules using psr-4 (**composer.json**). For example :

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Modules\\": "Modules/"
    }
  }
}
```

Creating a module is simple and straightforward. Run the following command to create a module.

```
php artisan module:make <module-name>
```

It is also possible to create multiple modules in one command.

```
php artisan module:make Blog User Auth
```